# How to share xml layout using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, share

I was searching everywhere, but can't found solution...

I have two xml layouts for share.
I have inflated and assigned to the views correctly.

```
shareLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.share_every_for_self_game_layout, null);
    contentView = (LinearLayout) shareLayout.findViewById(R.id.share_container_layout_id);
```

Problem is that the shared image is always empty.

Here is my code

```
private void shareResultToFacebook(){
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(contentView);

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(this, bitmap));
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }

}

//create bitmap from view and returns it
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    try {

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        view.buildDrawingCache();
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Global.logError("getBitmapFromView", e);
    }
    return null;
}


public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
                inImage, "", "");
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution

I have changed my **getBitmapFromView** method body

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(LinearLayout view) {
    try {

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(800, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return returnedBitmap;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Global.logError("getBitmapFromView", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And everything works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(LinearLayout view) {
    try {

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        view.buildDrawingCache();
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        }
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }catch (Exception e){
       // Global.logError("getBitmapFromView", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```